# Importing users into firebase using sha-1 hashed passwords

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In the simple case outlined below, the user will successfully import but I receive an `INVALID_PASSWORD` when I try to authenticate.

The `salt` and `passwordHash` where pulled from an LDAP user directory (apacheds) using the {SSHA} auth schema. When I run the following JS I receive the `passwordHash` I'm expecting:

```js
var sha1Hex = require('sha1-hex');

var saltHex =  Buffer.from("ktuF+dzYMQU=", 'base64').toString('hex');
var passwordHex = Buffer.from("demo", 'utf-8').toString('hex');

var hash = sha1Hex(Buffer.from(passwordHex + saltHex, 'hex'));
var hashBase64 = Buffer.from(hash, 'hex').toString('base64');
console.log(hashBase64);
```

**firebase CLM import command:**

```
firebase auth:import users.json --hash-algo=SHA1 --rounds=80
```

**users.json file:**

```json
{
  "users": [
    {
      "localId": "3c872eee-e86c-4b44-9840-bcebaac18f2c",
      "email": "test@example.com",
      "salt": "ktuF+dzYMQU=",
      "passwordHash": "BuapoGGKIdfGprfMFjj3N9I7Ljg=",
      "displayName": "Demo User",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Credentials that should work with imported user:**
Username: `test@example.com`
Password: `demo`

**Firebase web api login command (returns INVALID_PASSWORD):**

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('test@example.com', demo);
```

I'm not confident about the `--rounds=80` parameter, seems weird that needs to be specified at all when using sha1.  I've also tried with `--rounds=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying this out with Java MessageDigest SHA-1 to verify the password hash, one of our uber auth experts said that it looks like you're doing `passwordHash = SHA1(plainPassword + salt)`

However, the Firebase Auth system uses `passwordHash = SHA1(salt + plainPassword)`.

So I think if you switch that around, it should produce better results.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's going on.  The `passwordHash = SHA1(plainPassword + salt)` is the default behavior of the apacheds system we're currently using. Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the order of the password and hash.

The `hash-input-order` accept two values: `SALT_FIRST` or `PASSWORD_FIRST`.

In your case you want to do:

```
firebase auth:import users.json --hash-algo=SHA1 --rounds=80 --hash-input-order=PASSWORD_FIRST
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone like me that went hours finding a solution for this issue, please refer to [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1617).

Basically, `passwordHash` should be in Base64 encoding from un-hex-ed SHA1 hash. And `--rounds=1` works fine.

Comment: Is there a way to un-hex-ed SHA1 so that is in the raw value?  For example, we are trying to upload users to Firebase auth, we don't know the password, but we have the SHA1 value. How can we convert an already converted SHA1 into a raw binary format?

Comment: It depends on your code. If you're using MySQL, they provide `unhex` function.
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-unhex-function.php

Comment: Everywhere it says 80 rounds, but it won't work. 1 round worked for me. Thanks